# Gradle build fail - arm-linux-androideabi-ld: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to run an android project in android studio. During gradle sync, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Even when I try to execute the file from terminal, I get the same error:

```
Mycomputer:~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.0-rc1$ ./arm-linux-androideabi-ld 
bash: ./arm-linux-androideabi-ld: No such file or directory
```

I have tried the following:

1. try with build-tools version 25.0.3
2. giving all permissions for the
   file arm-linux-androideabi-ld (chmod 777)

Still I don't have any success.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missing the 32-bit libraries. Which cause the exception `No such file or directory` when executing them.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1
```

Additionally, you can check if the file is 32-bit to make sure this is the cause reason:

```
file arm-linux-androideabi-ld
```

Output:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped
```